# Can't pause web video in dynamic browser

Tags: c#, dynamic, browser, youtube

I created a console app in C# that plays videos from a file or from Youtube in a browser created at run time. The video will pause from a file but not from a YouTube video stream. It seems like it won't respond to input until the stream is finished. How can I make the browser respond or is this impossible?

Comment: can you share your code? which dynamics browser are you using?

Comment: Please don't respond if you don't know. Thanks.

Comment: I fixed the problem by pausing the process. Maybe not the best solution but it fixed the problem. I didn't know I had replies to this until today. Thank you anyway.